# Is it limit for youtube json connections?

Tags: php, json, youtube

I'm getting youtube views like that:

```
$video_ID = 'your-video-ID';
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&    alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
echo $views;
```

But sometimes i can see too many connections and yt back error ? So, how many queries into Youtube are possible for  day, for ip or domain?

Is there any chance to use API or something else to get a lot of data without problems ?

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are getting this error it means that the API servers have received too many calls from the same caller in a short amount of time.there is no limit kind of thing. you can simply use settimeOut if a request fails and then call again after few seconds you will be okay.

Or Read Here..

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_error_responses

Comment: I agree But this also got sufficient info and compatible too.

Comment: Yes, i saw quotas but... i'm using the script above without any API. Actually, before 6 months i had problems and errors. Now it's working perfectly.